# How to invoke API method that uses nested blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am using an API that has the following method signature:

```
- (BOOL)executeCommandIfConfirmed:
     (void (^)(void (^confirmationAnswer)(BOOL answer)))confirmationBlock;
```

Could someone provide an example of what a correct call would look like? I'm struggling.

Comment: Have you looked at a [tutorial on blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)?

Comment: This isn't "nested"; it's just a block with a parameter of block type.

Comment: Yes, tutorial on blocks is the first place I looked. It's in there I know, but I was not getting closer to it. "Nested" - I misunderstood what I was looking at.

Comment: (And from the answer I still don't understand -- back to the tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[object executeCommandIfConfirmed:^(void (^confirmationAnswer)(BOOL answer)) {
   confirmationAnswer(TRUE);
}];
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use a `UIAlertView`, you would have to create a class to be its delegate, as you usually would, but you would then pass the callback block to the constructor of the delegate and store it in a field. Then the delegate's `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` would call back into the callback block.

But if you're using blocks anyway, why not use [`PSAlertView`](https://github.com/steipete/PSAlertView), a block-based wrapper around `AlertView`:

```
[object executeCommandIfConfirmed:^(void (^confirmationAnswer)(BOOL answer)) {
   PSAlertView *alert = [PSAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Alert" 
          message:@"Do you want to continue?"];
   [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes" block:^{ confirmationAnswer(TRUE); }];
   [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"No" block:^{ confirmationAnswer(FALSE); }];
   [alert show];
}];
```

Comment: Does it work if you use it in your code? Without knowing what API you are using, we have no way of testing it for you.

Comment: Thanks Russell. Directly returning TRUE works, but the purpose of the API is to give the opportunity to get user feedback (presumably via a UIAlertView). I can't figure out how to work a UIAlertView to return TRUE or FALSE here. I haven't gone through the tutorial yet, but in the signature is "confirmationAnswer" a literal name? Could you give an example with some logic? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks Russell, this is brilliant! Works great and, even better, I understand what is going on. Awesome! (For me the PSAlertView class is called `PSPDFAlertView` and uses `initWithTitle:message:` constructor, maybe I have a different version, but it's from the link you provided and works great).